# ServiceStack Receiving posts without entity

Tags: http-post, servicestack

I've a scenario where I get changing post content. So I can't map it to an entity.

I need is to get the json body of the post.

I would like to create an entity with a Property "JSON" so if the url for this entity is called the body is filled.

Is there a way to do this ? or any other way fo have a generic endpoint for posts?

In WebAPI I created a parameterless method on a controller and analysed the body on my own.

Answer (score 0):

See this section on [Reading in and De-Serializing ad-hoc custom requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-in-and-de-serializing-ad-hoc-custom-requests) in ServiceStack's wiki.

E.g. you can use a custom request binder or get your Request DTO to implement `IRequiresRequestStream` to tell ServiceStack to skip the deserialization of the request DTO and directly retrieve the stream without populating the request DTO.